# How to wait for a finite stream bulk result

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a stream processing application built with spring cloud streams & kafka streams,
this system takes logs from an application and compares them to observations made by another stream processor
and produces a score, the log stream is then split by the score (above & below some threshold).

**The topology:**

[image]

**The issue:**

So my problem is how to properly implement the "Log best observation selector processor",
There are a finite amount of observations at the moment the log is processed but there may be a lot of them.

So I came up with 2 solutions...

1. Group & Window log-scored-observations topic by log id and then reduce to get the highest score. (Problem: scoring all observations may take longer then the window)
2. Emit a scoring completed message after every scoring, join with log-relevant-observations, use log-scored-observations global table & interactive query to check that every observation id is in the global table store, when all ids are in the store map to the observation with the highest score. (Problem: global table does not appear to work when only used for interactive query)

What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying?

- I'm hoping not to create any partition, disk or memory bottleneck.
- Everything has unique ids and tuples of relevant ids when the value is joined from log & observation.

(Edit: Switched text description of topology with a diagram & change title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #2 seems to work, but it emitted warnings because interactive queries takes some time to be ready - so I implemented the same solution with a Transformer:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class LogBestObservationsSelectorProcessorConfig {
    private String logScoredObservationsStore = "log-scored-observations-store";

    private final Serde<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple> logEntryRelevantObservationIdTupleSerde;
    private final Serde<LogRelevantObservationIdsTuple> logRelevantObservationIdsTupleSerde;
    private final Serde<LogEntryObservationMatchTuple> logEntryObservationMatchTupleSerde;
    private final Serde<LogEntryObservationMatchIdsRelevantObservationsTuple> logEntryObservationMatchIdsRelevantObservationsTupleSerde;

    @Bean
    public Function<
            GlobalKTable<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple>,
                Function<
                    KStream<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple>,
                    Function<
                            KTable<String, LogRelevantObservationIds>,
                            KStream<String, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple>
                    >
                >
            >
    logBestObservationSelectorProcessor() {
        return (GlobalKTable<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple> logScoredObservationsTable) ->
                (KStream<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple> logScoredObservationProcessedStream) ->
                        (KTable<String, LogRelevantObservationIdsTuple> logRelevantObservationIdsTable) -> {
            return logScoredObservationProcessedStream
                    .selectKey((k, v) -> k.getLogId())
                    .leftJoin(
                            logRelevantObservationIdsTable,
                            LogEntryObservationMatchIdsRelevantObservationsTuple::new,
                            Joined.with(
                                    Serdes.String(),
                                    logEntryRelevantObservationIdTupleSerde,
                                    logRelevantObservationIdsTupleSerde
                            )
                    )
                    .transform(() -> new LogEntryObservationMatchTransformer(logScoredObservationsStore))
                    .groupByKey(
                            Grouped.with(
                                Serdes.String(),
                                logEntryObservationMatchTupleSerde
                            )
                    )
                    .reduce(
                            (match1, match2) -> Double.compare(match1.getScore(), match2.getScore()) != -1 ? match1 : match2,
                            Materialized.with(
                                    Serdes.String(),
                                    logEntryObservationMatchTupleSerde
                            )
                    )
                    .toStream()
                    ;
        };
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    private static class LogEntryObservationMatchTransformer implements Transformer<String, LogEntryObservationMatchIdsRelevantObservationsTuple, KeyValue<String, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple>> {
        private final String stateStoreName;
        private ProcessorContext context;
        private TimestampedKeyValueStore<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple> kvStore;

        @Override
        public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.kvStore = (TimestampedKeyValueStore<LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple>) context.getStateStore(stateStoreName);
        }

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, LogEntryObservationMatchTuple> transform(String logId, LogEntryObservationMatchIdsRelevantObservationsTuple value) {
            val observationIds = value.getLogEntryRelevantObservationsTuple().getRelevantObservations().getObservationIds();
            val allObservationsProcessed = observationIds.stream()
                    .allMatch((observationId) -> {
                        val key = LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple.newBuilder()
                                .setLogId(logId)
                                .setRelevantObservationId(observationId)
                                .build();
                        return kvStore.get(key) != null;
                    });
            if (!allObservationsProcessed) {
                return null;
            }

            val observationId = value.getLogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple().getObservationId();
            val key = LogEntryRelevantObservationIdTuple.newBuilder()
                    .setLogId(logId)
                    .setRelevantObservationId(observationId)
                    .build();
            ValueAndTimestamp<LogEntryObservationMatchTuple> observationMatchValueAndTimestamp = kvStore.get(key);
            return new KeyValue<>(logId, observationMatchValueAndTimestamp.value());
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {

        }
    }
}
```